# Alternative for impure pipes in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I'm trying to write a simple todo app to learn Angular 6. In my app, todos can be completed or uncompleted and I want to display the number of uncompleted todos in footer component.

I have a todos component that shows the list of todos:

**todos.component.ts**

```
export class TodosComponent implements OnInit {
  todos: Todo[];
  constructor(private todoService: TodoService) { 
    this.todos = todoService.GetAll();
  }
  ngOnInit() {}
  ToggleTodoCompleted(id: number): void{
    this.todoService.Toggle(id);
  }
}
```

another component to add todo:

**todo-add.component.ts**

```
export class TodoAddComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private todoService: TodoService) { }
  ngOnInit() {}
  AddTodo(todoTitle){
    let todo = new Todo();
    todo.title = todoTitle;
    this.todoService.Add(todo);
  }
}
```

a footer component that I use an impure pipe to show the number of uncompleted todos in it:

**footer.component.ts**

```
export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {
  todos: Todo[] = [];
  constructor(private todoService: TodoService) { 
    this.todos = todoService.GetAll();
  }
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**uncompleted-todos.pipe.ts**

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'uncompletedTodos',
  pure: false
})
export class UncompletedTodosPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(todos: Todo[]): any {
    return todos.filter(t=>t.completed===false);
  }
}
```

**footer.component.html**

```
{{(todos|uncompletedTodos).length}} items left
```

and a simple service:

**todo.service.ts**

```
export class TodoService {
  private todos: Todo[] = [];
  GetAll(): Todo[]{
    return this.todos;
  }
  Add(todo: Todo): void{
    todo.id = this.todos.length + 1;
    todo.completed = false;
    this.todos.push(todo);
  }
  Toggle(id: number): void{
    let todo = this.todos.find(t => t.id === id); 
    todo.completed = !todo.completed;
  }
}
```

But I read in the Angular documentation that impure pipes can cause performance issues. So what is the alternative for that? How can I write my code without this impure pipe?

Comment: Just remove `pure: false` flag. Why do you need an impure pipe?

Comment: agreed. just remove "pure:false". Its already a pure function (meaning the result depends entirely on the input)

Comment: He is using an impure pipe because the change detection isn't happening. Give him a nalternative when you tell him to "remove the impure flag".

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner thanks for your comment, but unfortunately it doesn't work when I remove the tag and the component always displays "0 items left"!

Comment: trichetriche, there shouldn't be any issues with change detection.

Comment: @trichetriche then does it not make this and [X Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? I'm trying to get him to tell us what his real problem is. He tried to solve it with impure pipe but deep down there is something else.

Comment: @pixelbits so why use an impure pipe then ? And it seems there is since the OP itselfs says the results don't match.

Comment: @trichetriche, good question.. why use an impure pipe indeed...

Comment: Impure pipes are used for a single reason. They have one purpose. We're not in class, he is learning Angular, he asks for help. Instead of playing the guessing game, you should drive him to the solution, @BunyaminCoskuner

Comment: @pixelbits there's only one reason. If you don't know this reason, consider not commenting a solution ...

Comment: @trichetriche you're driving  him to the wrong solution...

Comment: @pixelbits oh you mean the solution given into the official documentation is not the right solution ? Please tell me what the "real" solution is, I'm eager to hear it.

Comment: @trichetriche yes, you gave him a quote from the docs. But it does not solve his problem either. With your solution, he'll learn that he should avoid pipes but won't know why.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner I didn't tell him to avoid pipes, I told him that the documentation advises not to use filtering or grouping pipes. He also told me he knows about the documentation, his issue is about the code he doesn't seem to get, hence my edit to give him a piece of code that would resolve his issue. So not only you people aren't helping him, but now you're trying to undermine my answer, just because.

Comment: @trichetriche I used impure pipes because I couldn't make it work any other way! actually it wasn't my first solution and I tried other ways before that and it didn't work. I agree with you about an issue in change detection but I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: @RezaHN well it seems you don't have an issue when you use impure pipes because as stated in the doc, impure pipes update the values everytime it can. When you remove the impure flag, it stops doing that, and it requires a change in the variable to trigger the pipe. That's why the documentation advises to put the logic inside your component (or service, like I showed you), because this would trigger a change detection (thanks to two-way binding)

Comment: @trichetriche I'm not trying to undermine your answer, I'm just trying to point out that he may have another problem lying underneath. As he stated, he tried other things and did not work, so at my first comment I was trying to get him say that. But instead, you jumped in with your condescending attitude.

Comment: Call my attitude whatever you want, he respected [ask] a question, provided a [mcve] with minimal code, and explained his issue correctly. If you want to play the guessing game and lose time, expect people that are actually here to help to be "condescending", and helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained [right in the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe)  :

> Angular doesn't provide pipes for filtering or sorting lists [...] This isn't an oversight. Angular doesn't offer such pipes because they perform poorly and prevent aggressive minification [...] **The Angular team and many experienced Angular developers strongly recommend moving filtering and sorting logic into the component itself**

This means you should get rid of your pipe, and put the logic directly inside your component.

**EDIT** for instance, to put the logic inside the feature itself :

```js
export class TodoService {
  private todos: Todo[] = [];
  GetAll(): Todo[]{
    return this.todos;
  }
  GetUncompleted() {
    return this.todos.filter(td => !td.completed);
  }
  ...
```

**EDIT 2** Your issue comes from the fact that you only assign the value of the todos once, at your components startup.

This means that when you add an item to the list of todos, you can't see the change, because you don't update the value.

For this, there is two solutions : the first one is to use getters.

Getters are special functions that will update their values whenever they're called. It's very simple to use. For instance, in your `todo.component`, it would give that :

```
get todos() { return this.todoService.getAll(); }
```

You can now use it in your template with

```
*ngFor="let todo of todos"
```

And this will be updated.

[**Here is a stackblitz to show you how getters work**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uttpfg?file=src/app/footer/footer.component.ts)

The second solution, is using RxJS. This is an event solution : when your list is getting updated, you have to trigger an event. Since this solution is more difficult, I have made [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dbyf1o?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftodo.service.ts) to help you understand it.

What happens basically is that whenever your list is getting updated, your components receive an event that tells them they have to update the list of todos.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I know about the documentation, but I don't know how to "put the logic directly inside your component"! I tried different ways but it doesn't work.

Comment: I had tried this before and I tried it again after your reply, but it doesn't solve the problem and  the component always displays "0 items left"!

Comment: Then you will have to provide a [mcve] on https://stackblitz.io that reproduces your issue, could you do that ?

Comment: here you are: [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dhegev](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dhegev)

Comment: I see, this issue happens because you aren't assigning your variables after you create a new todo. Do you want me to make a stackblitz with comments to explain it to you ?

Comment: thanks, I would be grateful if you could do that please!

Comment: **[Here you go !](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dbyf1o?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftodo.service.ts)** I'm also editing my answer to explain it briefly.

Comment: @RezaHN and **[here is the second one using getters](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uttpfg?file=src/app/footer/footer.component.ts)**.

Comment: thanks again @trichetriche, but the "getter" solution raised me another question: todos component updates after adding a todo, only by filling todos list once in constructor, and no getter is needed. but footer component doesn't update and it needs a getter. could you please explain me why?

Comment: Oh I see the issue. This is because when you write `return this.todos` in your service, you are returning a **reference** of the variable : this means that changes are repercuted on the spot. But when you write `return this.todos.filter(...)`, you create a new reference, **uncorrelated from the todos**. This means that it doesn't matter if you update the todos, it won't update the unfinished ones (because this isn't the same memory reference) @RezaHN